# How serially configure Datalogic M8300 barcode scanner (C#)

Tags: c#, service, serial-port, barcode-scanner

I've got a couple of 16 key M8300 serial barcode scanners that I'm writing a C# service for. I manage to receive codes and also to send feedback back to the scanner (print text to display, turn on/off LED and beeper).

Manual:
http://www.manualslib.com/manual/843135/Datalogic-Powerscan-D8330.html?page=206#manual

The scanners also have programmable function keys and I would like to be able to program these on the fly after each scan. The manual has a different chapter about changing the configuration through RS232 (serial) but I can't seem to get it to work.
http://www.manualslib.com/manual/843135/Datalogic-Powerscan-D8330.html?page=220#manual

To test this I'm trying to turn off the aiming system first. I believe the code below does this but instead it only shows the configuration string on the display instead of changing the configuration:

```
char delimiter = '-';
char carriageReturn = '\x0D';
serialPort.Write(scannerID + delimiter + "$+Bj0$-" + carriageReturn);
```

Is what I want even possible in the first place? I hope someone can give me some tips and insights.

Comment: Malformed URLs to manuals.

Comment: Sorry my bad, they should work now.

Comment: Do you have ACK/NAK enabled?  Which response do you receive?  Have you tried comparing the RS-232 command results with the keypad configuration method (i.e. page 96 of that manual)?

Comment: 2-way is enabled, but I found the problem which I explained below

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that what I tried to do is only possible when the scanner is sitting in its cradle. I received an alternate manual from my supplier that was more clear on this subject.

What I wanted is to be able to change the configuration while scanning, but this is apparently not possible.